# load static html file in vue.js , vue-router and webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I am using vue.js and webpack to develop the homepage for my friend. however he want to keep some old pages which using  javascript and jquery(cdn).
Can I do some config in vue-router to do something like this.

```
/home --> Vue Project Homepage
/photo ---> Vue router change the router-view to photo.vue
/download ---> Go to the directory "/download" in project and load the index.html in "/download" directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [Redirect and Alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) of Vue router:

"Redirecting is also done in the routes configuration. To redirect from /a to /b:"

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/a', redirect: '/b' }
  ]
})
```